# how to get the first letter of a non latin string with php

Tags: php, substr

For grabbing the first letter of a string i use `substr`

```
$string = "John doe";
echo substr($string,0,1);
// output: J
```

But this does not work when the string is, per example in russian of with accented letter

```
$string = "Марина Матвиенко";
echo substr($string,0,1);
// output: nothing

$string = "Éduard Rousseaux";
echo substr($string,0,1);
// output: nothing
```

Do i need to convert the string into latin first or is there another way to grab the first letter from non latin characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `mb_substr` when using multibyte chars.

```
echo mb_substr($string,0,1);
```